# Adding items to an existing AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

So I need to show an AlertDialog with one item, then execute a get request, after it's resolved, I need to add more items to the dialog.

I tried the below code without success

```
var list = arrayOf("aa")
val b = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
b.setItems(list, onItemClickListener)
val dialog = b.create()

executeGetRequest() {
   list += "New Item"
   val adapter = dialog.listView.adapter as ArrayAdapter<*>
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

However, updating the existing item is working:

```
list[0] = "Updated Item"
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
val list = arrayListOf("aa")
val b = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
val onItemClickListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
    // code
}
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
setAdapter(adapter, onItemClickListener)

executeGetRequest() {
   list.add("New Item")
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
b.show()
```